# Binding Button Text to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I'm trying simple things, such as setting a Listview of buttons and binding the text of these buttons to the element in the list.

Here is the test MainPage.

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        ObservableCollection<Lot> lotList = new ObservableCollection<Lot>();

        lotList.Add(new Lot(1));
        lotList.Add(new Lot(2));
        lotList.Add(new Lot(3));
        lotList.Add(new Lot(4));
        lotList.Add(new Lot(5));

        this.BindingContext = lotList;
    }
```

Which is pretty straitforward, creating a List of items and adding items into it.

The XAML looks like this:

```
            <ListView x:Name="lotListView" HorizontalOptions="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Button Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Which is a common thing to do I guess?

I do have the correct amount of buttons being displayed but nothing written in them.
My question is: how can I make the buttons Text property get the name from the items in the list?
I thought the ToString method would have been invoked but it doesn't seem so.

The Lot class, as requested:

```
    public class Lot
{
    private int id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Lot(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = "Lot n° " + id.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share us the Lot model?

Comment: I just did, thanks for the interest !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is change the `{Binding}` to `{Binding Name}`

```
  <ListView x:Name="lotListView" HorizontalOptions="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Button Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll marck that as an answer.
Do you think that this type of binding is the way "best" way to do it ?

Comment: No one will be able to answer a "best" question without a lot more context, but what you have is part of a perfectly normal pattern of doing things, and is fine :)

Comment: This is perfectly fine. You can also use {x:Bind}, but this, for me, looks a lot better.